# store value fetched from an arraylist into an int variable

Tags: jsp

```
    <%-- JSTL foreach tag example to loop an array in jsp --%>
    <c:forEach var="window" items="${listOFSchools}">
    <c:out value='${window.school_id }'/>
    <%

    SchoolDisplayService CDS = new SchoolDisplayService();

   List<Schooltable> list = CDS.getSchools(window.school_id );

    %>
```

I want to pass the school_id fetched from the array list "listOFSchools" to the method getSchools(). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tag set `<c:set />`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html) to set `school_id`

```
<c:forEach var="window" items="${listOFSchools}">
 <c:set var="schoolId" value="${window.school_id}" />
```

And for accessing a [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) variable `schoolId` inside scriptlets [see my anwer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19807997/1031945)
In your case,

```
<%
    SchoolDisplayService CDS = new SchoolDisplayService();

    int schId = (Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("schoolId");

    List<Schooltable> list = CDS.getSchools(schId);
%>
```