# In JSP, how to branch based on Spring variable?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, attributes, branch

My JSP page accesses several attributes, as in the following section:

```
    <div id="ep-error-title">Error ${errorCode}: ${errorMessage} <!-- error number and text -->
    </div>
```

What I want to do is to be able to access the errorCode within JSP statements, so I can do something like:

```
    <% if ("1".equals(errorCode)) { %>
    <%@ include file="stuffFor1.inc" %>
    <% } else { %>
    <%@ include file="stuffForEverythingElse.inc" %>
    <% } %>
```

The problem is the EQUAL test; how do I access the value (which was shown by ${errorCode} when outside the JSP section) when I'm inside the JSP section?
Sorry if this seems obvious, but I haven't worked hardly at all with either Spring or JSP.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL) for branching logic rather than embedding scriptlets.  There are many tutorials available online, but basically you need to add a project dependency:

If you are building with Maven it would look like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Include it at the top of your JSP pages:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

You can then use JSTL elements such as `<c:if>`, `<c:choose>`, `<c:when>`, and `<c:otherwise>`. For example, in your situation it looks like you might do the following:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${errorCode == '1'}">
    <%@ include file="stuffFor1.inc" %>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <%@ include file="stuffForEverythingElse.inc" %>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Having said all that... if you **really** want to access the variable in a scriptlet, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807156/accessing-a-jstl-variable-inside-a-scriptlet).